# eclipse android emulator buttons don't work

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I'm developing an android app on Eclipse Juno.
The android emulator starts up properly loads my splash screen
and then moves on properly but none of the buttons on the emulator
work. All of the buttons that represent the buttons on the phone do
nothing when clicked and also when I try to click any buttons on my
app nothing happens. Anyone have this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. start the eclipse
2. start android virtual device manager.
3. select the AVD which you use.
   4.select edit in right corner.
4. in the hardware option select new.
5. add keyboard lid support and keyboard support.
6. set value yes for this properties.
7. now start emulator this will work.

Answer (score 1):

In the new ADT, they changed the way the keyboard support works for emulators...so you need to manually add support for it.  If you go to your AVD Manager then edit your AVD, in the Hardware section click New and add 'Keyboard support' and set the value to 'yes'.  That should fix it for you.